# How to put in BOLD the title in a seaborn factorplot

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization, seaborn

How can I the title in BOLD?
By now I have just changed the font size. I tried with font weight, but it does not exist.

```
    sns.plt.title('I AM A TITLE').set_fontsize('18')
```

Comment: Maybe this can works: `sns.plt.title('\textbf{I AM A TITLE}').set_fontsize('18')`

Comment: `plt.title(..., weight='bold')`

Comment: what seaborn function are you using?

Comment: factorplot. But the legend is set to False.

Comment: @Hackerman did not work.

Answer (score 10):

Here is the answer:

```
    sns.plt.title('I AM A TITLE', weight='bold').set_fontsize('18')
```

[image]